# Removing the class name from Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions constants

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Is there any way to *include* the constants from [`Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node/SaveOptions.html) in the same way as I can with a module?

I am currently using

```
save_options = Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::FORMAT | Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::AS_HTML
puts html.serialize(:save_with => save_options)
```

and would much rather have

```
html.serialize(:save_with => FORMAT | AS_HTML)
```

I can improve it a little by using

```
include Nokogiri::XML

html.serialize(:save_with => Node::SaveOptions::FORMAT | Node::SaveOptions::AS_HTML)
```

or

```
html.serialize(:save_with => Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions.new.format.as_html)
```

but neither of those is ideal. Does anyone have a better way? I see no reason why this couldn't be a module instead of a class, as the advantages of creating an object are slim to non-existent.

Answer (score 1):

The safest thing will be doing it “by hand” for the constants you need. If you write this in your scope the constants will be defined with the right value:

```
class YourClass # or module YourModule
  %w(FORMAT AS_HTML).each do |konst|
      const_set(konst, Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions.const_get(konst))
  end
end
```

If the number of constants is big you can automate the creation a little bit. The problem is that is an all or nothing approach, and things like class names are also constants, so they will get imported too. It doesn’t seem to be a problem for the constants you are looking for.

```
class YourClass
  Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions.constants.each do |konst|
    const_set(konst, Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions.const_get(konst))
  end
end
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using `html.serialize(:save_with => FORMAT | AS_HTML)` and want to simplify it, why don't you use:

```
html.to_html
```

It outputs with these flags:

```
DEFAULT_HTML = FORMAT | NO_DECLARATION | NO_EMPTY_TAGS | AS_HTML
```

That's the standard HTML output default for Nokogiri.

You can drill down to use `write_to` if you want all the power.

Both `to_html` and `write_to` are documented in [Nokogiri::XML::Node](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html). You might want to nose around in the source too.